# Security with DynamoDB for a multi-tenant application

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, multi-tenant, serverless

In a multi-tenant system where we have multiple customers. Each of those customers will have multiple users. What's the best way to ensure users from `customer1` can never access data that belongs to `customer2`. We do have customer_id in all of our tables. I came across fine-grained access control but not sure if it could be used for this use-case. If not, what are my options? What are the best-practices to ensure security here?

Comment: Unfortunately you only get fine grained access control implemented at the database level if the partition key of the table matches the user's amazonid. This then puts significant contraints on your data modelling. For this reason you might need to consider access control in your business logic, which is less secure.

Comment: I am happy to use it  atleast in the tables that have customerId in the partition key. How should I go about that?

Comment: See the answer below from @CruncherBigData. Basically, you use an IAM policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html) is a relevant reference to your use case, please see the `dynamodb:LeadingKeys`. Assuming you are doing CRUD operations against tables that has customer as hash key and users as range keys.